# ArrayBlockingQueue - is it really Concurrent?

Tags: java, multithreading, api, concurrency, blockingqueue

Not a single operation of `ArrayBlockingQueue` is concurrent with any of its other operations; they always take the same lock. Even for the `size()` method it takes a lock.

```
 public int size() {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
        try {
            return count;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

While for the implementation of `LinkedBlockingQueue` you have two locks: put and take.
And for `size()` it uses `AtomicInteger` so doesn't need a lock.

So my question is: why is this implementation in the concurrent package - is `ArrayBlockingQueue` really concurrent?

Comment: It can be used in a concurrent setting---that's the point.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ArrayBlockingQueue` is in the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package because multiple threads can use the object concurrently without thread-safety problems.

The ability to use multiple methods at the same time is *not* what the object is made for.

Comment: I would add that the "concurrent" package is a colleciton of utils for building concurrent applications.  the utils are all "thread-safe".  Some are more intrinsically "concurrent" than others.